# Change the color of a Border element in ListBox when item is selected

Tags: wpf, datatemplate

I have the following `ItemTemplate` defined for a `ListBox`.

```
<ListBox.ItemTemplate>
    <DataTemplate>
        <Grid Margin="0 4 0 4">
            <Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
                <ColumnDefinition Width="Auto" SharedSizeGroup="grp1" />
                <ColumnDefinition Width="*" />
                <ColumnDefinition Width="Auto" SharedSizeGroup="grp2" />
            </Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
            <Grid.RowDefinitions>
                <RowDefinition Height="Auto" />
                <RowDefinition Height="Auto" />
                <RowDefinition Height="Auto" />
            </Grid.RowDefinitions>
            <Border BorderBrush="Black" BorderThickness="0 0 0 1" Grid.Column="0" Grid.Row="0" Grid.ColumnSpan="3">
                <TextBlock Text="..." FontSize="16" />
            </Border>
            <TextBlock Grid.Column="0" Grid.Row="1" Grid.ColumnSpan="3" Text="..." />
            <StackPanel Grid.Column="0" Grid.Row="2" Orientation="Horizontal">
                <TextBlock Grid.Column="0" Grid.Row="2" Text="..." />
            </StackPanel>
        </Grid>
    </DataTemplate>
</ListBox.ItemTemplate>
```

The thing is, when the item is selected, all the `TextBlock`'s foreground colors change, but the `Border`'s color remains black:

Unselected:

[image]

Selected:

[image]

How can I change the color of the `Border` to match the color of the `TextBlock`s?

Answer (score 0):

The item selection colors are defined in the `ControlTemplate` for `ListBoxItem`. This is the container into which your `ItemTemplate` is injected so the colors are already set by the time your `DataTemplate` is being rendered. To override it you need to set the `ListBox.ItemContainerStyle` to a new `Style` with a `ControlTemplate` that does what you want. A simple example is below. To keep it as close as possible to what you're seeing now, use the option in Blend to "Edit a Copy" of the current template that is being rendered under your current theme. You can then edit just the parts you want and keep the rest of the template the same.

```
<Style x:Key="ListBoxItemBasicStyle" TargetType="{x:Type ListBoxItem}">
    <Setter Property="SnapsToDevicePixels" Value="true"/>
    <Setter Property="OverridesDefaultStyle" Value="true"/>
    <Setter Property="Template">
        <Setter.Value>
            <ControlTemplate TargetType="{x:Type ListBoxItem}">
                <Grid SnapsToDevicePixels="true">
                    <Border x:Name="Border" Background="{TemplateBinding Background}" BorderBrush="{TemplateBinding BorderBrush}" BorderThickness="{TemplateBinding BorderThickness}"/>
                    <ContentPresenter HorizontalAlignment="{TemplateBinding HorizontalContentAlignment}" VerticalAlignment="{TemplateBinding VerticalContentAlignment}"/>
                </Grid>
                <ControlTemplate.Triggers>

                <!-- Change IsSelected SelectedBackgroundBrush to set the selection color for the items -->
                    <Trigger Property="IsSelected" Value="true">
                        <Setter Property="Background" Value="{DynamicResource SelectedBackgroundBrush}" TargetName="Border"/>
                    </Trigger>

                    <Trigger Property="IsEnabled" Value="false">
                        <Setter Property="Foreground" Value="{DynamicResource DisabledForegroundBrush}"/>
                    </Trigger>
                </ControlTemplate.Triggers>
            </ControlTemplate>
        </Setter.Value>
    </Setter>
</Style>
```

Comment: I'm not sure we're talking about the same thing. I don't want to change the color itself, I just want the line in my schreenshot to also be white when selecting. I don't want it to remain black as in the schreenshot.